# BeautifulSoup: Get the contents of a specific table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tabular

[My local airport](http://www.iaa.gov.il/Rashat/he-IL/Airports/BenGurion/informationForTravelers/OnlineFlights.aspx?flightsType=arr) disgracefully blocks users without IE, and looks awful. I want to write a Python scripts that would get the contents of the Arrival and Departures pages every few minutes, and show them in a more readable manner.

My tools of choice are [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) for cheating the site to believe I use IE, and [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for parsing page to get the flights data table.

Quite honestly, I got lost in the BeautifulSoup documentation, and can't understand how to get the table (whose title I know) from the entire document, and how to get a list of rows from that table.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This is not the specific code you need, just a demo of how to work with BeautifulSoup. It finds the table who's id is "Table1" and gets all of its tr elements.

```
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
bs = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = bs.find(lambda tag: tag.name=='table' and tag.has_attr('id') and tag['id']=="Table1") 
rows = table.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name=='tr')
```

Comment: You can even chain find commands inside the lambda (to better filter, since I had multiple tables but they didn't have IDs) !
`table = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name=='table' and tag.find(lambda ttag: ttag.name=='th' and ttag.text=='Common Name'))`

Comment: FYI, "has_key" is now deprecated. Use has_attr("id") instead. I will edit the original response as well.

Answer (score 19):

Here is a working example for a generic `<table>`. *(Though not using your page due javascript execution needed to load table data)*

Extracting the table data from [here](http://worldpopulationreview.com/countries/countries-by-gdp/#worldCountries) GDP (Gross Domestic Product) by countries.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
html = ... # read your html with urllib/requests etc.
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, parser='lxml')

htmltable = soup.find('table', { 'class' : 'table table-striped' })
# where the dictionary specify unique attributes for the 'table' tag
```

Bellow the function parses a html segment started with tag `<table>` followed by multiple `<tr>` (table rows) and inner `<td>` (table data) tags. It returns a list of rows with inner columns. Accepts only one `<th>` (table header/data) in the first row.

```
def tableDataText(table):    
    """Parses a html segment started with tag <table> followed 
    by multiple <tr> (table rows) and inner <td> (table data) tags. 
    It returns a list of rows with inner columns. 
    Accepts only one <th> (table header/data) in the first row.
    """
    def rowgetDataText(tr, coltag='td'): # td (data) or th (header)       
        return [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.find_all(coltag)]  
    rows = []
    trs = table.find_all('tr')
    headerow = rowgetDataText(trs[0], 'th')
    if headerow: # if there is a header row include first
        rows.append(headerow)
        trs = trs[1:]
    for tr in trs: # for every table row
        rows.append(rowgetDataText(tr, 'td') ) # data row       
    return rows
```

Using it we get (first two rows).

```
list_table = tableDataText(htmltable)
list_table[:2]

[['Rank',
  'Name',
  "GDP (IMF '19)",
  "GDP (UN '16)",
  'GDP Per Capita',
  '2019 Population'],
 ['1',
  'United States',
  '21.41 trillion',
  '18.62 trillion',
  '$65,064',
  '329,064,917']]
```

That can be easily transformed in a `pandas.DataFrame` for more advanced manipulation.

```
import pandas as pd

dftable = pd.DataFrame(list_table[1:], columns=list_table[0])
dftable.head(4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 18):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML)

# the first argument to find tells it what tag to search for
# the second you can pass a dict of attr->value pairs to filter
# results that match the first tag
table = soup.find( "table", {"title":"TheTitle"} )

rows=list()
for row in table.findAll("tr"):
   rows.append(row)

# now rows contains each tr in the table (as a BeautifulSoup object)
# and you can search them to pull out the times
```

Comment: any ideas how to go to a specific table when there are no id or title to differentiate... for example.. I want the third table with in the html file... (there are no other indicators).

Comment: @ihightower: `soup.find('table')[2]` would get you the third `table`. (You'd want to check the length before doing this though, just to be safe.)