# Python: Mechanize and BeautifulSoup not working on a shared hosting computer

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, shared-hosting

I am writing a small site decorator to [make my local airport site work with standard HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935658/beautifulsoup-get-the-contents-of-a-specific-table).

On my local computer, I use Python's `mechanize` and `BeautifulSoup` packages to scrape and parse the site contents, and everything seems to work just fine. I have installed these packages via `apt-get`.

On my shared hosting site (at [DreamHost](http://dreamhost.com)) I have downloaded the `.tar.gz` files, extracted the packages, renamed the directories (e.g., from `BeautifulSoup-3.1.0.tar.gz` to `BeautifulSoup`) and tried to run the command.

I've got a bizarre error with BeautifulSoup; I don't know if it's about an older version of Python on Dreamhost, about directory names, or other reason.

```
[sanjose]$ python
Python 2.4.4 (#2, Jan 24 2010, 11:50:13) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20061115 (prerelease) (Debian 4.1.1-21)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup                           
>>> import mechanize                                                  
>>> url='http://www.iaa.gov.il/Rashat/he-IL/Airports/BenGurion/informationForTravelers/OnlineFlights.aspx?flightsType=arr'
>>> br=mechanize.Browser()                                                                                                
>>> br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)')]                                
>>> r=br.open(url)
>>> html=r.read()
>>> type(html)
<type 'str'>
```

I've done this to show that the input is indeed a string. Now let's run the command that works in my local computer:

```
>>> soup    =   BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  File "/home/adamatan/matan.name/natbug/BeautifulSoup/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1493, in __init__
    BeautifulStoneSoup.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/adamatan/matan.name/natbug/BeautifulSoup/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1224, in __init__
    self._feed(isHTML=isHTML)
  File "/home/adamatan/matan.name/natbug/BeautifulSoup/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1257, in _feed
    self.builder.feed(markup)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/HTMLParser.py", line 108, in feed
    self.goahead(0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/HTMLParser.py", line 148, in goahead
    k = self.parse_starttag(i)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/HTMLParser.py", line 268, in parse_starttag
    self.handle_starttag(tag, attrs)
  File "/home/adamatan/matan.name/natbug/BeautifulSoup/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1011, in handle_starttag
    self.soup.unknown_starttag(name, attrs)
  File "/home/adamatan/matan.name/natbug/BeautifulSoup/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1408, in unknown_starttag
    tag = Tag(self, name, attrs, self.currentTag, self.previous)
  File "/home/adamatan/matan.name/natbug/BeautifulSoup/BeautifulSoup.py", line 525, in __init__
    self.attrs = map(convert, self.attrs)
  File "/home/adamatan/matan.name/natbug/BeautifulSoup/BeautifulSoup.py", line 524, in <lambda>
    val))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/sre.py", line 142, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, 0).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Any ideas?

Adam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using BeautifulSoup version 3.1.0 which is for Python 3.x. Use a 3.0 version of BeautifulSoup for Python 2.x.