# Python Bs4: How to retrieve row in table based on specific 'td' value that row

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-table, beautifulsoup

If I have a website page with multiple tables and I want to retrieve the source code for a specific row from a specific table based on a keyword in beautifulsoup4, how can I go about doing that using the `find` or `find_all` methods (or any other methods in that matter)
[image]

Using the table above, lets say I want to retrieve the row that contains the keyword **"ROW 1" (or "A", "B", "C" etc.)** and only that row, how can I go about that?

Comment: It would be best to show the actual HTML, but one solution would be to create a list of all elements (`.find_all()`) that are `tr` and then index to the appropriate row (perhaps `[1]` in this case).

Comment: you can use regex for this purpose.

Comment: Provide the source in your example.

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ would you put the regex search inside the .find(insert regex call here)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrived example below but with bs4 4.7.1 you can use pseudo-class css selectors of [`:has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) and [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to specify pattern of `tr` (row) that **has** `td` (table cell) which **contains** *'wanted phrase'*. A table identifier is passed as well to target the correct table (id here to make things simple). `select` will return all qualifying tr elements; use `select_one` if only the first match is required.

```
soup.select('#example tr:has(> td:contains("Row 1"))')
```

py

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<table id="example">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Col1</th>
    <th>Col2</th>
    <th>Col3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
<table id="example2">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Col1</th>
    <th>Col2</th>
    <th>Col3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Not Row 1</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Not Row 2</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>

'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml') #'html.parser'
soup.select('#example tr:has(> td:contains("Row 1"))')
```

Answer (score 0):

Grab the entire html with pandas and do the following (this code is untested)

```
import pandas as pd

html_table = 'From your web scrapping'
df = pd.read_html(io=html_table)
df.loc[1]  # Will give you all the information for the first row
```

I'd suggest spending 10 minutes to learn pandas it will really help out. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html

Comment: Will do! is "html_table = 'From your web scrapping'" equivalent to "source = BeautifulSoup(siteSource, "html.parser")"?

Comment: No, you'll want to grab the html table element from bs4. It will look somewhat like this `html_table = soup.find('table')` like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935658/beautifulsoup-get-the-contents-of-a-specific-table